# Using a case statement to show certain columns in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

Is there a way to do use a CASE statement to display certain columns in a select statement?

At the moment I'm using the following SQL to do this

```
BEGIN
IF( @ISUSERROLE = 1)
     SELECT 
    t       PONumber                      = [RAH_PONumber]
           ,RAType                       = rt.[RAT_Type]
           ,ChargeableAmount             = [RAH_ChargeableAmount]
     FROM [T_RA_Header] rh
     INNER JOIN dbo.T_RA_Type rt ON rt.RAT_ID = rh.[RAH_RAT_ID]
     INNER JOIN dbo.T_RA_Status rs ON rs.RAS_ID = rh.[RAH_RAS_ID]
     WHERE
          rh.RAH_RAI_ID = @RAI_ID

    ELSE IF (@ISUSERROLE = 2)
          SELECT   
           PONumber                     = [RAH_PONumber]
          ,RANumber                     = [RAH_RANumber]
          ,RAType                       = rt.[RAT_Type]
          ,RAStatus                     = rs.RAS_Status
          ,RAUploadedBy                 = [RAH_UploadedByUserName]
          ,UploadedOn                   = [RAH_UploadedOn]
          ,ChargeableAmount             = [RAH_ChargeableAmount]

     FROM [T_RA_Header] rh
     INNER JOIN dbo.T_RA_Type rt
          ON rt.RAT_ID = rh.[RAH_RAT_ID]
     INNER JOIN dbo.T_RA_Status rs
          ON rs.RAS_ID = rh.[RAH_RAS_ID]
     WHERE
          rh.RAH_RAI_ID = @RAI_ID
END
```

From this is it possible to use a CASE statement?? Or is what I have done the only way

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which is presumably SQL Server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SQL query returns a well-defined set of columns.  You cannot change the number, types, or names of the columns, although you can change the contents.

`CASE` is an expression that returns a single value, which can be a column in the result set.

Hence, you cannot use `CASE` to change the number of columns.

Your only alternative would be dynamic SQL, where you set the columns you want in a query string and then execute the query string.

Answer (score 0):

with [case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
declare @ISUSERROLE int = 1
declare @select_1 varchar(2000)
declare @select_2 varchar(2000)
declare @main_sql varchar(4000)
declare @final_set varchar(8000)

set @select_1 = 'PONumber = [RAH_PONumber],
                 RAType = rt.[RAT_Type],
                 ChargeableAmount = [RAH_ChargeableAmount]'

set @select_2 = 'PONumber= [RAH_PONumber],
                 RANumber= [RAH_RANumber],
                 RAType  = rt.[RAT_Type],
                 RAStatus= rs.RAS_Status,
                 RAUploadedBy= [RAH_UploadedByUserName],
                 UploadedOn= [RAH_UploadedOn],
                 ChargeableAmount = [RAH_ChargeableAmount]'

set @main_sql = ' FROM [T_RA_Header] rh
                INNER JOIN dbo.T_RA_Type rt
                 ON rt.RAT_ID = rh.[RAH_RAT_ID]
                INNER JOIN dbo.T_RA_Status rs
                 ON rs.RAS_ID = rh.[RAH_RAS_ID]
                WHERE
                 rh.RAH_RAI_ID = '+convert(varchar,@RAI_ID)+''


set @final_set = 'select '+case  when @ISUSERROLE  = 1 then @select_1 else @select_2 end+@main_sql
--print @final_set
exec (@final_set)
```